# Unable to monitor message inside SELECT statement

Tags: ibm-midrange, clp

I have this code which will work even if the QTEMP/FILE1 is already existing.

```
CRTPF FILE(QTEMP/FILE1) RCDLEN(133)
MONMSG MSGID(CPF5813)
```

But when I put the same code inside SELECT...ENDSELECT, then the MONMSG can't handle the existing file and will have an error due to CPF5813.

```
SELECT                                       
      WHEN (&A *EQ &B) THEN(DO)
          CRTPF FILE(QTEMP/FILE1) RCDLEN(133)
          MONMSG MSGID(CPF5813)
          ... other codes
      ENDDO
      OTHERWISE (DO)
          ... other codes
      ENDDO
ENDSELECT
```

How will I able to monitor the message inside SELECT statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message `CPF5813` is not the message to be monitored here, it is a diagnostic message. It is message `CPF7302` which is raised by `CRTPF` and which must be monitored.

If you want to check that `CPF5813` is the diagnostic sent, you have to use `RCVMSG` like below :

```
   pgm

   dcl        &excpkey *char 4
   dcl        &diagid *char 7

   select
      when       (1 *eq 1) then(do)
         crtpf      file(qtemp/file1) rcdlen(133)
         monmsg     CPF7302 *n do
            rcvmsg     msgtype(*last) keyvar(&excpkey) rmv(*no)
            rcvmsg     msgtype(*prv) msgkey(&excpkey) rmv(*no) msgid(&diagid)
            if         (&diagid *ne cpf5813) do
               sndpgmmsg  msgid(cpf9898) msgf(qcpfmsg) msgdta('qtemp/file1 not created for an +
                     unexpected reason: ' *cat &diagid *bcat 'see joblog for details') +
                     msgtype(*escape)
            enddo
         enddo
      enddo
      otherwise  (do)
         /* do something */
      enddo
   endselect

   endpgm
```

Comment: It works as expected. But please help me to understand more.
Why is it that when I try to do: MONMSG MSGID(CPF5813 CPF7302)
I'm unable to handle it. Is there something if the statements are under the SELECT? Note: I just want to skip the error message once the file is already created.

Comment: `monmsg cpf7302` should be sufficient, just tested and it works, `cpf5813` is never sent as an exception

Comment: @Asymptote MONMSG doesn't work for diagnostic, informational, or completion (*DIAG, *INFO, *COMP) messages, only escape, notify, or status (*ESCAPE, *NOTIFY, *STATUS)

Comment: Thank you @Charles. This makes it easier to understand why my expectation is not correct.